# jQuery get content between <div> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This'll probably be easy for someone:

```
var x = '<p>blah</p><div><a href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=brd&FlightID=2997227&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=9088" target="_blank"><img src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=bsr&FlightID=2997227&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=9088" border=0 width=300 height=250></a></div>';
```

How do I extract only the portion between the div tags `<div>I want this</div>`
Don't focus on the `<a>` tag as the content could be different inside the div.

Comment: Is x a js string or are you trying to extract content from your page?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The [JavaScript String doco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) gives a bunch of methods for manipulating strings. (Also, perhaps you could edit your code to be valid JS?)

Comment: Yeah good question. I should have been more specific. x is a STRING.

Comment: @user460114. See my edit below.

Comment: to read `text` content .text() does it for you but to read `html` content you need .html() .

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This is probably what you need:

`$('div').html();`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/f3uFj/)

This says get the `div` and return all the contents inside it.  See more here: http://api.jquery.com/html/

If you had many `div`s on the page and needed to target just one, you could set an `id` on the `div` and call it like so

`$('#whatever').html();`

where *whatever* is the `id`

**EDIT**

Now that you have clarified your question re this being a string, here is a way to do it with vanilla js:

```
var l = x.length;
var y = x.indexOf('<div>');
var s = x.slice(y,l);
alert(s);
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/f3uFj/1/)**

1. get the length of the string.
2. find out where the first `div` occurs
3. slice the content there.

Comment: What's vanilla js? I'm using jQuery. Your code give error x.slice is not a function. Probably cos I'm not using vanilla js.

Comment: @user460114 Vanilla JS is plain JS, i.e., using no libraries etc.

Comment: $('#whatever').text(); is best option.

Comment: What should i do to get the data-attributes along with html ?

Answer (score 16):

jQuery has two methods

```
// First. Get content as HTML
$("#my_div_id").html();

// Second. Get content as text
$("#my_div_id").text();
```

Answer (score 3):

Give the div a class or id and do something like this:

```
$("#example").get().innerHTML;
```

That works at the DOM level.

Answer (score 3):

Use the below where x is the variable which holds the markup in question.

```
$(x).find("div").html();
```

Comment: If the content inside the div can change, it may be reasonable to assume that there may be a div contained inside the div, which will cause this to break. `children()` instead of `find()` will fix this issue (assuming that the div will always be at the top level)

Comment: @Matthew - .html() always gives the html of the first matched element. So there will not be any problem if it has nested div. Moreover my answer was as per the user's markup provided in the question.

Comment: +1 because this answer specifies how to supply the `string` (or - I would imagine - DOM content - to the function

Answer (score 1):

use jquery for that:

```
$("#divId").html()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you give an if to the div than:

```
$("#my_div_id").html();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = '<p>blah</p><div><a href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=brd&FlightID=2997227&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=9088" target="_blank"><img src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=bsr&FlightID=2997227&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=9088" border=0 width=300 height=250></a></div>';
$(x).children('div').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the text method [`text()`] to get text in the div element,
by identifing the element by class or id.

Comment: Please explain better your answer, the part about the *id* is not so clear.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me

```
var content = '<p> demp text </p>';
$('#wordContent').html(content);
$('#wordContent').html($('#wordContent').text());
```