# Getting inner HTML of a specific div in a different page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to have a web page where I'll put lots of divs and inside each of those divs there will be be different content. Based upon a condition I want to display the content of a specific div inside a JQuery dialog. Is it possible to get the html content of a particular div in a web page?

Comment: Is there a reason why `var html = $("#myDiv").html()` wouldn't work here?

Comment: show us the sample of the code

Comment: may be this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854009/jquery-get-content-between-div-tags

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, the way you suggested would perfectly work if that div existed at the page the user currently is viewing. That's why I asked the question, a div in a different page.

Comment: Is this "other page" on the same domain?

Comment: @MikeJM You may want to edit your OP to make that clear then, as it currently just says 'get the html content of a particular div in a web page' - no mention of being a different page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post("some.php",function(data) {
    var content = $(data).find(".someClass");
});
```

allow only same domain

like this ? or i misunderstand ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var x, y;
x = 0;
y = 1;

switch (myCondition)
{
case 'condition (n)' || x = y:
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://samedomain.com/pageWithContent.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#targetDiv').html(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error occurred while loading content.');
            }
    });
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

If the content you are trying to display is has a bit of data to load then this is a good option, but if the data is not that much then try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#itemChangingMyCondition').bind('change', function() {
        switch ($(this).attr('value')) 
        {
            case 'First item':
                $('#targetDiv').html($('#relativeDiv')).html());
                break;
            case 'Second item':
                $('#targetDiv').html($('#relativeDiv')).html());
                break;
            default:
                $('#targetDiv').html($('#defaultDisplayDiv')).html());
                break;
        }
    });
});
```