# Is it possible to access the content of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to access the content of an object?
At the moment it logs 0.
It also logs the document but under a `#document`, I'm not sure if it's possible to access that outside the console.

```
<div id="objectContainer" ></div>

<script>
    $("#objectContainer").html('<object id="objectID" class="webPage" data="http://www.example.com"/>');

    $("#objectID").on("load", function () {
        var v = document.getElementById("objectID");
        console.log(v);
        descendents = v.getElementsByTagName('*');
        console.log(descendents.length);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There are no HTML tags inside `#objectID`, so children count equals to zero.

Comment: About `.innerHTML` and `.html()` - once again: there is no HTML content inside `#objectID`, so they return empty strings. Moreover, what do you mean by _<object> content_?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with native javascript.

```
console.log(v.outerHTML);
```

Comment: As i was afraid of, a blank line as well.

Comment: @clankill3r by looking at your code...object ID has no html.....so if you want the full content, use outerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use that:

```
val output = $("#objectContainer").val();
```

But be careful because aa mentioned before if there is no html or text inside that div you may get 0 or null as a result

Comment: `.val()` is not appropriate way for this. For `#objectContainer` it can simply be `.html()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be thinking of `.text()` or `.html()` jQuery method.

Another SO answer: [jQuery get content between <div> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854009/jquery-get-content-between-div-tags)