# How to pull an value (number) and divide it by another number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website that I'm working on and there needs to be a bit of jquery added that will pull the value out of a raised paragraph tag, and divide it by 5, and then display that value below the original paragraph tag. I've been searching for some helpful code and I think I've found the right technique but when I put it in the code it returns nothing and I haven't been able to figure out why (novice with jquery)

the HTML set up is fairly simple -

```
<div>
     <p class="raised">$100</p>
     <p class="votes"><!--this is where I'd like the output--></p>
</div>
```

From searching around on google this code seems to be the most logical (to me) -

```
var num1 = $("p.raised").val(),
    num2 = 5,
    result = parseInt(num1, 10) / parseInt(num2, 10);
$(".votes").append(result);
```

But when I try this the number in the raised tag isn't gathered by the .val() call and nothing else works (might be because of the $ symbol?), can someone help lead me in the right direction?

Comment: yes it's because the `$` symbol. `parseInt("$100")` will return 0 while `parseInt("100$")` returns 100. `parseInt` parses until a non-number is reached.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get content between <div> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854009/jquery-get-content-between-div-tags)

Comment: What `console.log($("p.raised"))` and `console.log($("p.raised").val())` tell you? If values are correct, then continue the logic!

Comment: Better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `val()` to `text()`. `val()` get a tag's value. But what you want is the content of the paragraph. So that's `text()`. `html()` also works. But you have to get rid of the first character of num1. Here:

```js
var num1 = $("p.raised").text().substring(1),
    num2 = 5,
    result = parseInt(num1, 10) / parseInt(num2, 10);
    
$(".votes").text(result);
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="raised">$100</p>
  <p class="votes"><!--this is where I'd like the output--></p>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num1 = $(".raised").html().replace('$',''),
    num2 = 5,
    result = parseInt(num1, 10) / parseInt(num2, 10);
    console.log(result)
$(".votes").append(`$${result}`);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.