# jQuery split text into runs including text not inside <span> or <div> tags

Tags: html, jquery

How do I break HTML into a sequence or array of "runs" where a run is a contiguous length of text, either inside a `<span>` or between `<span>`s.

For instance:

```html
<div id=input>
  The rain in <b>Spain</b> falls <i>mainly</i> in the <u>plain</u>
</div>
```

I would like to get a sequence of text "runs" as jQuery objects, strings, or something like:

```
[
   "The rain in",
   "<b>Spain</b>",
   "falls",
   "<i>mainly</i>",
   "in the",
   "<u>plain</u>"
]
```

Basically I want the runs as "child" elements but also include the text between child elements. I tried the following but

```
return $("*", "#input").map(function() {
    return $(this)[0].outerHTML
  }).toArray()
```

but this just returns the child elements not the text between:

```
[
   "<b>Spain</b>",
   "<i>mainly</i>",
   "<u>plain</u>"
]
```

For context, my goal is to translate this text into OpenXML for export to Microsoft, and correctly identify each runs with its font size, weight, color, etc.

[jQuery get content between <div> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854009/jquery-get-content-between-div-tags)
[Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I see jQuery `.contents()` returns this, with an additional attribute `nodeType` that lets you see what kind of content it is:

```
   return $($div).contents().map(function() {
     // this.nodeType == 1 for top level text or 3 for child divs
    return $(this)[0].outerHTML || $(this).text()
  }).toArray()
```

yields

```
[
    "The rain in ",
    "<b>Spain</b>",
    " falls ",
    "<i>mainly</i>",
    " in the ",
    "<u>plain</u>"
]
```